# Google Fit API history limit?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

So I'm trying to read the google fit history using the android API, but I'm coming across an annoying limitation. I seem to only be able to read the past week or so's worth of history, even though there is vastly more data (according to the google fit app). The code I'm using to read the data is below

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    //long startTime = 0l;

    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Log.i(TAG, "Range start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.i(TAG, "Range end: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, readRequest).setResultCallback(
            new com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(DataReadResult result) {
                    //Log.i(TAG, result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                    int i = 0;
                    for (Bucket bucket : result.getBuckets()) {
                        for (DataSet dataSet : bucket.getDataSets()) {
                            //Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                            for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                                Log.i(TAG, ++i + "");
                                Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
                                Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                                Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                                            " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

And yet according to logcat, there's lots of empty days

```
0-01 22:24:21.000 32590-32624/? I/MainActivity: Range start: 2015-09-01 10:24 PM
10-01 22:24:21.000 32590-32624/? I/MainActivity: Range end: 2015-10-01 10:24 PM
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32606/? V/Fitness: Received batch result
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.380 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 1
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.383 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-23 4:41 PM
10-01 22:24:21.384 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-23 10:14 PM
10-01 22:24:21.384 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 3093
10-01 22:24:21.384 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.384 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 2
10-01 22:24:21.384 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.384 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-23 10:27 PM
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-24 5:14 PM
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 13582
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 3
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-25 11:54 AM
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-25 10:23 PM
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 15395
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 4
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.385 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-25 10:34 PM
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-26 10:23 PM
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 15975
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 5
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-26 10:25 PM
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-27 10:24 PM
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 14562
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 6
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.386 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-27 10:24 PM
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-28 10:24 PM
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 16200
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 7
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-28 10:24 PM
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-29 10:21 PM
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 13371
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 8
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.387 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-29 10:37 PM
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-09-30 10:19 PM
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 3383
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: 9
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity: Data point:
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Type: com.google.step_count.delta
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Start: 2015-09-30 10:45 PM
10-01 22:24:21.388 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    End: 2015-10-01 7:26 PM
10-01 22:24:21.389 32590-32590/? I/MainActivity:    Field: steps Value: 12805
```

Any insight into why I can't read before the 23rd (as of writing) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

By default your request will query only local data stored on the device. To include data from Google servers add `.enableServerQueries()` to the `DataReadRequest.Builder`:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .enableServerQueries()
        .build();
```

> [enableServerQueries()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/DataReadRequest.Builder.html#enableServerQueries())
>
> Enable querying the Google Fit server to fetch query results, in case
>   the local store doesn't have data for the full requested time range.
>   Server results will be combined with local results into one DataSet.